# .textClipping file appeared on the desktop mysteriously

Tags: macos, mac

My friend came to me today and said a random file has appeared on his desktop. I didn't think much of it but I have no clue what it is.

The file is a .textClipping and consist of this text:

```
bot

search

LOAD MORE MESSAGES
```

But when I convert it to a .txt file it has this. (Not the massive HTML chunk):

```
bplist00—XUTI-Data‘ 
_public.utf16-plain-text_public.utf8-plain-text[public.html_$com.apple.traditional-mac-plain-textON


bot



Search



LOAD MORE MESSAGES
_'


bot



Search



LOAD MORE MESSAGES
O5u<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"><div class="title-wrap title-wrap-dark" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px 20px 0px 0px; border-width: 0px 0px 1px; border-top-style: initial; border-right-style: initial; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: initial; border-top-color: initial; border-right-color: initial; border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2); border-left-color: initial; border-image: initial; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0588235) 0px 1px 0px; min-height: 56px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 1026px; display: flex; -webkit-box-align: center; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0; z-index: 100; -webkit-app-region: drag;"><div class="header-toolbar" style="margin: 0px -12px 0px 50px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; display: flex; -webkit-box-pack: center; justify-content: center; -webkit-box-align: center; align-items: center; flex-shrink: 0;"><div class="theme-dark" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline;"><div class="search" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 8px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; overflow: visible; z-index: 100; -webkit-app-region: no-drag;"><div class="search-bar" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0980392); box-shadow: none; display: flex; -webkit-box-align: stretch; align-items: stretch; flex-shrink: 0; border-radius: 3px; box-sizing: border-box; width: 144px; height: 28px; transition: width 0.2s ease-in-out;"><div class="DraftEditor-root" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: 500; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; height: inherit; text-align: initial; position: relative; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex: 1 1 0%; line-height: 22px; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); overflow: hidden;"><div class="DraftEditor-editorContainer" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: none; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; height: inherit; text-align: initial; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0); position: relative; z-index: 1;"><div aria-describedby="placeholder-5k4ah" class="public-DraftEditor-content" contenteditable="true" role="textbox" spellcheck="false" style="margin: 0px; padding: 3px 6px 20px; border: 0px; outline: none; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; height: inherit; text-align: initial; -webkit-user-modify: read-write-plaintext-only; overflow-x: auto; overflow-y: hidden; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;"><div data-contents="true" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline;"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="5k4ah" data-offset-key="9sk03-0-0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline;"><div data-offset-key="9sk03-0-0" class="public-DraftStyleDefault-block public-DraftStyleDefault-ltr" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; white-space: nowrap; direction: ltr; text-align: left; display: inline-block; min-width: 1px;"><span data-offset-key="9sk03-0-0" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 14px; vertical-align: baseline; min-width: 1px;"><br class="Apple-interchange-newline"><br data-text="true"></span></div></div></div></div></div></div><div class="search-bar-icon" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; width: 30px;"><i class="icon icon-search-bar-eye-glass visible" style="display: inline-block; transition: all 0.1s linear; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 6px; opacity: 0.3; width: 18px; height: 18px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 2; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;); transform: rotate(0deg);"></i><i class="icon icon-search-bar-clear" style="display: inline-block; transition: all 0.1s linear; position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 6px; opacity: 0; width: 18px; height: 18px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index: 2; transform: rotate(0deg); background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;);"></i></div></div></div></div><div class="separator theme-dark" style="margin: 0px 8px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; width: 1px; height: 22px; background-color: rgba(247, 247, 248, 0.0980392);"></div><button type="button" class="" style="font-family: Whitney, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border: 0px; cursor: pointer; position: relative; padding: 0px; border-radius: 4px; background-color: transparent; width: 30px; height: 30px; -webkit-app-region: no-drag;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 11px; vertical-align: baseline; transition: opacity 0.2s; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-size: 26px; background-position: 50% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; opacity: 0.6; background-image: url(&quot;/assets/567632a2702aed0296e15d68d6cae738.svg&quot;);"></span></button><button type="button" class="" style="font-family: Whitney, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border: 0px; cursor: pointer; position: relative; padding: 0px; border-radius: 4px; background-color: transparent; width: 30px; height: 30px; -webkit-app-region: no-drag; margin-left: 8px;"><span style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 11px; vertical-align: baseline; transition: opacity 0.2s; display: block; width: 30px; height: 30px; background-size: 26px; background-position: 50% center; background-repeat: no-repeat; opacity: 0.6; background-image: url(&quot;data:image/svg+xml;base64,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&quot;);"></span></button></div></div><div class="content flex-spacer flex-horizontal" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; display: flex; -webkit-box-orient: horizontal; -webkit-box-direction: normal; flex-direction: row; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex: 1 1 0%; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(54, 57, 62); min-height: 1px;"><div class="flex-spacer flex-vertical" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; display: flex; -webkit-box-orient: vertical; -webkit-box-direction: normal; flex-direction: column; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex: 1 1 0%; overflow: hidden; min-width: 1px; position: relative;"><div class="messages-wrapper" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; display: flex; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex: 1 1 0%; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0; background-color: rgb(54, 57, 62);"><div class="scroller-wrap" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; position: relative; display: flex; min-height: 1px; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex: 1 1 0%; overflow: hidden;"><div class="messages scroller" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-family: inherit; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; min-height: 1px; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex: 1 1 0%; overflow-y: scroll; contain: layout; overflow-x: hidden;"><div class="has-more" style="margin: 10px 0px 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; outline: 0px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-family: Whitney, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; height: 36px; display: flex; -webkit-box-align: center; align-items: center; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(54, 57, 62);"><button type="button" style="font-family: Whitney, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; border: 1px solid rgb(47, 49, 54); cursor: pointer; background: rgb(50, 53, 58); height: 30px; width: 747px; margin: 6px 6px 6px 19px; color: rgb(114, 137, 218); text-align: center; -webkit-box-flex: 1; flex-grow: 1; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 500; border-radius: 3px; text-transform: uppercase;">LOAD MORE MESSAGES</button></div><div class="message-group hide-overflow" style="margin: 0px 6px 0px 20px; padding: 20px 0px; border-width: 0px 0px 1px; border-top-style: initial; border-right-style: initial; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: initial; border-top-color: initial; border-right-color: initial; border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0392157); border-left-color: initial; border-image: initial; outline: 0px; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-family: Whitney, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; vertical-align: baseline; overflow: hidden; display: flex; word-wrap: break-word; box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-user-select: text; color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-variant-ligatures: normal; font-variant-caps: normal; letter-spacing: normal; orphans: 2; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: 2; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(54, 57, 62);"><br class="Apple-interchange-newline">O'


bot



Search



LOAD MORE MESSAGES
7P\É‘˛6w6°
```

Its probably nothing but I just wanted to make sure its nothing bad. 
He swears it just appeared one night so I might as well check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is nothing. Your friend accidentally dragged text that was selected from a web page onto his desktop.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TextClipping)

> textClipping is an extension used by Macintosh computers for strings
>   of text, used since Mac OS 9 was released. When a string of text is
>   selected and dragged to the desktop or everywhere of a Macintosh
>   computer, the computer automatically converts it into a .textClipping
>   file. The file formed can conveniently be dragged to any text box to
>   replicate the exact text, including its formatting.

Comment: Cool thanks for the help, Just wanted to be safe!